# SSO in OAuth2Client in Spring Boot Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have been reading about OAuth2 integration in Spring Security and how Authentication/Authorization is implemented via third party identity provider (such as Google).

I achieved SSO login using `@EnableOauth2Sso` annotation and adding following to my `application.properties`:

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: 8d...f5e
      clientSecret: 2d...1b
      accessTokenUri: https://sso.domain.com/oauth/token
      userAuthorizationUri: https://sso.domain.com/oauth/authorize
      scope: openid
    resource:
      userInfoUri: https://sso.domain.com/userinfo
```

This seemed too magical and I had no idea what was going on under the hood. Following the guide on Spring's official site for [Manual Configuration of OAuth2 Client](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/#_social_login_manual) I see that it switches to `@EnableOauth2Client` instead of `@EnableOauth2Sso` and it says:

> First off we can inject an OAuth2ClientContext and use it to build an authentication filter that we add to our security configuration

What is `OAuth2ClientContext`? I checked on official [API Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/OAuth2ClientContext.html) and it just says that it's a interface but still not sure what it exactly is and how it is used.

Am I missing something or the official documentation insufficient? I am still unable to get hold of how OAuth2ClientContext, OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter and OAuth2RestTemplate work together to perform authentication in Spring via SSO.

Please point to any right bits of documentation to grasp this down to the basics. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need an Oauth2 Client example? You won't find much documentation on the subject, an example is the best one can get.

Comment: @EugenCovaci Example would be good too. My aim is to understand how internally this is happening without the magic annotations. With that knowledge, I would want to customize some aspects after authentication. I find it weird that it's not documented on how different bits and pieces work.

Comment: The best I could find is this: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth2-authentication-with-reddit But it is bloated, it doesn't present the essential.

Comment: This one https://www.baeldung.com/spring-oauth-login-webflux is for WebFlux. If you wait until tomorrow, I'll make a simple example for Spring Web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a ready-to-run [example](https://github.com/ecovaci/oauth2example/tree/master). It authenticates the client against the authorization server also accesses a protected resource from the resource server.

I'm still working on documenting the source code and completing the README. If you have questions, feel free to ask me.

Comment: Looks very helpful. I just took a high-level view of this and looks like you're using `HttpSecurity.oauth2login()` for client implementation. Going through [Spring Boot Guide](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/#_social_login_manual) I noticed that it manually creates a filter to login to the protected server.

If I understand correctly, the client does a `OAuthRestTemplate` call to userinfo endpoint to load Authentication object. What if I want to customize this object? I saw there was some reference of `PrincipalExtractor` interface, does that apply to your solution?

Comment: @int-main It seems that manually creating that filter gives you more control over the process. Regarding the PrincipalExtractor interface, I see no reason not to work, feel free to try it, here is an example: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-principal-authorities-extractor. Regarding the "call to userinfo endpoint" actually it doesn't make the call to load the Authentication object, all it wants is the result of the call as String (I'm not sure I understood your question correctly).

Comment: Your repository was a great help. I was able to implement SSO login via `HttpSecurity.oauth2Login()` using your example as reference. One more question, this authenticates anybody who has SSO service account. Now how do I implement application specific filtering (to check if they have access or not). Example: Websites let you sign in with Google and if your account doesn't exist, they go through sign up flow. How will that be done in case of `HttpSecurity.oauth2Login()`. This is what I was looking into `PrincipalExtractor` inteface for.

Comment: @int-main Great news. You said `Websites let you sign in with Google and if your account doesn't exist, they go through sign up flow.`. Actually, this is not accurate. The sign-in/sign-up process is entirely the authorization server responsibility - the client application is unaware of the fact that the user perform sign-in directly or goes through a sign-up first. Unfortunately, there is no out-of -the-box feature for sign-up, therefore you'll have to implement one (by using a custom login page and adding a link bellow the login form pointing to the sign-up page).

Comment: I probably didn't put it well. I meant although sites have sign-in via third provider, they do require a user account in local database. Since the time I posted my last comment, I came across [UserInfoEndpointConfig](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/oauth2/client/OAuth2LoginConfigurer.UserInfoEndpointConfig.html) which allows for a custom version of `userService` (something like `PrincipalExtractor`). Seems like this is the way to handle when user is visiting for the first time.

Comment: @int-main No, they do not require a user account in local database.  You seem to want to decorate the client's security context with some new extra info.